# An equivalence principle for gauge theories

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, gauge-theory, equivalence-principle

In GR there is the equivalence principal, stating that in an arbitrary gravitational field, no local non-gravitational experiment can distinguish a freely falling, non-rotating system from a uniformly moving system in absence of the gravitational field.
Or in mathematical terms, we can always choose a reference system in which the Christoffel symbols vanish.

In gauge theory, we can always find a coordinate system in the internal space, i.e. a section in the principal bundle, such that the connection 1-form vanishes. Let's assume electromagnetism, but it should hold also for the strong and weak interaction. Can we state an 'electromagnetic'-equivalence principle, i.e. that there in no local (i.e. at a specific point) electromagnetic experiment which can distinguish a charge 'falling' in an electromagnetic field from a charge outside every electromagnetic field?

My doubts: In GR the fact that we can choose a reference frame in which the Christoffel symbols vanish is equivalent to the statement of the equivalence principle. I have doubts about the equivalence of the vanishing connection 1-form and the 'electromagnetic equivalence principal', since accelerated charges radiate and their is self interaction. However I only require the equivalence principle locally, i.e. at one point (maybe this saves it). But a spherical mass, e.g. a point mass does not radiate gravitational waves when accelerated, so I assume their is also no self interaction. This is a big difference to electromagnetism.

Comment: How do you want to free fall with an electron?

Comment: With falling I mean, that ab electron moves in a electromagnetic field

Comment: But that's no free fall, as in gravity. In the moving frame of the electron, there will still be a force. You can't gauge it away as in GR.  Look at *classical* electric force. If you move in the same way as a charge in an electric field, how can this be done? There is no frame that can move freely along with it, as there is for a mass freely falling in a gravity field.

Comment: There's an by Weinberg based on scattering amplitudes that gravitational scattering amplitudes (more precisely, exchange of a graviton at tree level by two masses in the low energy limit) is consistent only if the equivalence principle holds. The same constraint applied to $U(1)$ gauge theory leads to conservation of charge. If I have time later I'll try to dig it up and write it as a real answer.

Comment: One of the founders of gauge theory refers in [these notes](https://academic.oup.com/ptp/article/64/6/2207/1864763) to the vanishing of a gauge field at a single point as 'a kind of generalized principle of equivalence' on P.2215. Interpreting the meaning of this, e.g. as a 'falling electron' which doesn't seem to make sense, is another story.

Comment: @Duepietri I think your are right. The electron is not free falling in spacetime but the the electron is free falling in the fiber, i.e. in the gauge group/internal space. However I am not sure about the interpretation of a movement in the fiber. What is the free fall equivalent to a movement in a single fiber

Comment: In the fiber (tangent to 4d spacetime), there will always be a real gauge field present. There is no gauge that can transform a real field away (contrary to gravity). I'm not sure what you mean by an electron falling in the fiber. The electron can only fall in spacetime.

Comment: It is said that the curved gauge spaces are equivalent to gravity, but the curved spaces are simply no extensions of spacetime. One *could* argue that the extra space dimensions in string theory provide, but then there should be seven extra dimensions: three for the strong force, three for the weak, and one for the em.

Comment: I think you can always choose a gauge such that the connection 1-form vanishes. Or what do you mean by there is no gauge that can transform a real field away

Comment: I mean that if a gauge field (the em field, for example) is present, it will *always* be present ( if you "fall freely" in the field, it won't disappear.).

Comment: But the gauge field is not real, it is  connection in a principal bundle. And in fact we can gauge transform without changing the real objects and in this sense, we can move freely in the gauge group without changing something.